# Is there any better deep clone methods for list?

Tags: c#, deep-copy

So I needed a method to deep clone. I wanted one list of cards to equal another list of cards, but then I also wanted to modify one of the clones.

I made a method to copy the list like this:

```
    public List<Card> Copy(List<Card> cards)
    {
        List<Card> clone = new List<Card>();
        foreach (var card in cards)
        {
            clone.Add(card);
        }
        return clone;
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
        _cards = new List<Card>();
        _thrownCards = new List<Card>();

        _cards = Copy(_thrownCards);
        _thrownCards.Clear();
```

I'm not experienced in C#, but somehow my gut feelings tells me my copy method could be made simpler. Isn't there any other way you could deep copy a list? I tried using [MemberWiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks), but that just created references to the same object, not cloning it(maybe I misinterpreted the MemberWiseClone method).

Do anyone have any tip how simply clone a list object?

Comment: You can clone the list with `cards.ToList()` but if `Card` is a reference type you'll need to clone each list element as well to get a deep copy.

Comment: Your method is not a deep cloning, because all `Card` instances are not cloned but just copied to another list (assuming they are not structs).

Comment: I just want to point out that since your Copy function creates and returns a `new List<Card>()` you don't actually need to initialize _cards first. You could use your function like this: `_thrownCards = new List<Card>(); ...; _cards = Copy(_thrownCards); _thrownCards.Clear();` Also, what you are actually doing in your Copy function is a shallow clone. Here's a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) about the difference between the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a real deep-copy because the `Card` instances are still the same, only the list is different. You could have this much simpler:

```
List<Card> cloneList = cards.ToList();
```

You need to "copy" all properties of the `Card` instances as well:

```
public List<Card> Copy(List<Card> cards)
{
    List<Card> cloneList = new List<Card>();
    foreach (var card in cards)
    {
        Card clone = new Card();
        clone.Property1 = card.Property1;
        // ... other properties
        cloneList.Add(clone);
    }
    return cloneList;
}
```

You could also provide a factory method that creates a clone of a given `Card` instance:

```
public class Card
{
    // ...

    public Card GetDeepCopy()
    {
        Card deepCopy = new Card(); 
        deepCopy.Property1 = this.Property1;
        // ...
        return deepCopy;
    }
}
```

Then you have encapsulated this logic in one place where you can even access `private` members(fields, properties, constructors). Change the line in the `Copy` method above to:

```
cloneList.Add(card.GetDeepCopy());
```

Comment: Would you recommend putting the copy method on `Card` itself? `cloneList.Add(card.DeepCopy())`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, got an error and misinterpreted my own structure. This worked fine, so I marked it as solution!

Answer (score 1):

To have deep copy, you would need have something like that:

```
public List<Card> Copy(List<Card> cards)
{
    List<Card> clone = new List<Card>();
    foreach (var card in cards)
    {
        clone.Add(new Card 
        {
          property1 = card.property1;
          property2 = card.property2; // and so on
        });
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Of course if `property1` and `property2` are also a refference type objects, then you would have to go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
List<Card> _cards = _thrownCards.ConvertAll(Card => new Card(<card parameters here>));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike *shallow* copy when we copy references only

```
 public List<Card> Copy(List<Card> cards) {
   return cards.ToList();
 }
```

In case of *deep* copy we have to clone *each item*:

```
 public List<Card> Copy(List<Card> cards) {
   return cards
     .Select(card => new Card() {
        //TODO: put the right assignment here  
        Property1 = card.Property1,
        ...
        PropertyN = card.PropertyN,
     }) 
     .ToList();
 }
```